# BerkleyDb JE DbDump Extraordinary memory usage

Tags: java, berkeley-db-je

We use BDB JE in one of our applications, and `DbDump` for backing up database. The interesting things happened one day. `DbDump` starts to throw out an `OutOfMemoryError`. Postmortem analysis shows that a lot of memory is used by internal BDB nodes (`IN`). It seems like BerkleyDB reads all the dataset in memory while backing it up, which is quite strange for me.

Another strange fact is that this behavior only visible when the environment is open by the application itself. So when DbDumb is the only client who open environment everything seems to be fine.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using `DbBackup` instead? I know they do two different things, but if all you're looking to do is backup a database, there's no need to pull it all into memory when simply copying the files elsewhere will do.  Or is the command line ability the deciding factor here?

Comment: AFAIK, `DbBackup` could be used only inside application which open environment. We want some way to do hot backup of BDB databases without changing application for this requirement.